# dynamic programming matrix fill for Knapsack

Tags: algorithm, matrix, language-agnostic, dynamic-programming

If I have the following constraints:

```
values = {$1,$2,$3,$4}  
items = {blue,yellow,green,red}  
weights = {1,2,3,4}  
capacity = 4
```

and I want to fill out my matrix  with the **columns representing item weights** and the **rows representing number of items chosen**:

```
       1      2     3    4    

1     $1     $1    $1    $1
      {1}    {1}   {1}   {1}    
2     $1     $1    $3      $3
      {1}    {1}  {1,2}   {1,2}  
3     $1     $1    $3      $3    
      {1}    {1}  {1,2}   {1,2}
4     $1     $1    $3      $3      <--- should be 4?
      {1}    {1}  {1,2}    {1,2}
```

What I was expecting to see is a solution that provides `4` as the  as the correct dollar amount, but I get `3`.  The numbers in braces `{}` represent the **one based** indices to look up the items in.  Where did I go wrong with my matrix fill?

Comment: There is a problem in the cell above the right/bottom one, which should say $4 {1,3}. But even if it didn't, the right/bottom cell should have said $4 {4}, so it went wrong there too.

Comment: @harold so at the location (3,3) it should say {1,3} ?

Comment: I meant location (3, 4) ie directly above the cell you pointed at

Answer (score 1):

The solution goes like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

// m[a][b] = NOWAY => There's no way to represent 
// weight `b` with first `a` items
const int NOWAY = -1;
typedef vector<vector<int>> vvi;

const int values[] = {1, 2, 3, 4}; 
const string items[] = {"blue", "yellow", "green", "red"}; 
const int weights[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
const int capacity = 4;
const int itemcount = 4;

void rec(vvi const & m, int represent, int mx, vvi & sol);

int main() {
    // m[i][j] -- total value
    // i -- items 1..i were taken
    // j -- total weight of those items
    vvi m(itemcount + 1, vector<int>(capacity + 1, NOWAY));

    // No items weight nothing. The other values we're yet to build
    m[0][0] = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= itemcount; ++i) {
        m[i] = m[i - 1];
        int w = weights[i - 1];
        // Find new representations
        for (int j = capacity - w; j >= 0; --j) {
            if (m[i][j] != NOWAY) {
                m[i][j + w] = max(m[i][j + w], m[i][j] + values[i - 1]);
            }
        }
    }
    // Output table
    for (int i = 0; i <= itemcount; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= capacity; ++j)
            m[i][j] == NOWAY ? cout << "x " : cout << m[i][j] << ' ';
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    // Find the index of the best solution (it's always in the last row)
    int mxi = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= capacity; ++i)
        if (m.back()[mxi] < m.back()[i])
            mxi = i;
    // Recurse to get all the representations
    vvi solutions;
    rec(m, mxi, itemcount, solutions);
    // Output them
    for (int i = 0, ilen = solutions.size(); i < ilen; ++i) {
        cout << '{';
        bool f = true;
        for (int j = 0, jlen = solutions[i].size(); j < jlen; ++j) {
            if (!f) cout << ", ";
            cout << items[solutions[i][j]];
            f = false;
        }
        cout << "}" << endl;
    }
}

vector<int> path;
void rec(vvi const & m, int represent, int mx, vvi & sol) {
    if (represent == 0) {
        sol.push_back(path);
        return;
    }
    if (mx <= 0) return;
    for (int i = mx - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        if (represent < weights[i])
            continue;
        if (m.back()[represent - weights[i]] == m.back()[represent] - values[i]) {
            path.push_back(i);
            rec(m, represent - weights[i], i, sol);
            path.pop_back();
        }
    }
}
```

It returns

```
0 x x x x
0 1 x x x
0 1 2 3 x
0 1 2 3 4
0 1 2 3 4

{red}
{blue, green}
```

(By the way, consider training at [USACO](http://cerberus.delos.com:790/usacogate) or [Topcoder](https://www.topcoder.com/).)

Comment: Shouldn't the first row be all 1's (not `1 0 0 0`)? Each cell normally represents the best you can do with items weighing less than or equal to the current weight (otherwise your final check has to loop over some values to find the best one, rather than just returning the corner cell).

Comment: @Dukeling You cannot represent weight of 2 and more having only one item with weight of 1.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph I said "less than or equal to". And I'm not saying it's wrong, just that that's not the way it's normally done (and it's slightly slower). And why isn't the second row `1 2 3 0` then, the last `2` indicates only a weight `2` item, but the weight is supposed to be `4`?

Comment: @Dukeling Yep, sure, there was a bug. Thanks.